# What is the best way to calculate difference between TIMESTAMP values in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to achieve the following behavior in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4?

I have a table in DB with a column that contains TIMESTAMP values. I need to iterate over all records in this table and do some actions if the difference between TIMESTAMP value in this column and current time greater  than some amount of months or days.

What is the best practice to do it? Convert TIMESTAMP value to the Unix time or use some class that handles dates by itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look for a way where you don't have to iterate through all the records in the table.

Comment: What are your expected inputs and outputs? Please explain.

Comment: What is this timestamp? From where you're getting it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your results like this:

```
result = YourModel.where("created_at >= ?", 5.days.ago)
```

or

```
result = YourModel.where(created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now)
```

Them you can just iterate over the result:

```
result.each do |item|
  #Do something with item
end
```

OBS: I'm assuming the TIMESTAMP column is created_at, but you can replace that for your column.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to iterate over it via find_each method, right?

Comment: You can do it with `each `method. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine to do that if you have an index on that column.  If not, you should add a migration to index the column.

After that, you could add a method on the model that finds all records older than your criteria like this:

```
class Model
  def self.older_than(timeframe)
    where('column_with_timestamp < ?', timeframe)
  end
end
```

You could then query like `Model.older_than(1.month.ago)` which would return the records where the timestamp is older than the specified date.  You can then iterate over them like normal